# Teste de integração ligado a um FTP

Tags: git, ftp, integração-contínua, travis-ci

É possível e-ou se há uma ferramenta que possibilite que eu envie determinados aquivos de um projeto para um FTP após este passar em um teste de integração contínua (Travis-ci por exemplo)?

A ideia é que após eu efetuar um *commit* e o teste for concluído e passar em todos os testes, as alterações que foram consequentemente efetuadas com sucesso sejam publicadas automaticamente.

Hhá outras formas de ter um resultado próximo disso ou talvez alguma solução melhor?

Caso seja de ajuda, atualmente uso como ferramenta de versionamento o Git, como gerenciador de repositórios uso o Github e para integração continua uso Travis-ci.

Comment: Já experimentou usar as `notifications` do Travis? dá para fazer correr um URL por exemplo: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Webhook-notification

Comment: Bacana, não sei se é a melhor solução mas pode ajudar a resolver caso eu mesmo crie um script para publicar as alterações.

Answer (score 2):

Compartilhei minha pergunta e alguns colegas desenvolvedores me ajudaram com algumas sujestões. Cheguei a este link que é uma pagina sobre Custom Deployment do travis-ci especificamente:

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/

Também me indicaram outra solução. Utilizar um gerenciador de tarefas como o [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) ou [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) por exemplo, e usar um callback como `after_success` (http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Build-Lifecycle) do travis-ci para executar uma tarefa que faça a funcionalidade de conectar com um FTP e enviar os arquivos desejados.

Creio que ambas as ideias são validas embora cada uma seja melhor para situações específicas acredito.

Pesquisei e encontrei alguns complementos que podem ajudar com isso:

**Grunt:**

https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ftp

**Gulp:**

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ftp

Também imaginei uma possível mecânica com o comentário do @Sergio. Posso usar [Webhook notification](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Webhook-notification) para enviar uma notificação para um URL específico e a partir deste realizar o deploy.